# Opencart and VQMOD issue: Could not load controller in vq2-system_engine_controller.php

Tags: opencart, vqmod

I am using Opencart 1.5.6.1 and VQMOD 2.4.1. I have just installed eWay Rapid 3.0 extension and in the checkout, I get this error:

```
Notice: Error: Could not load controller payment/eway! 
in (.....)\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 47
```

Line 47 is `trigger_error('Error: Could not load controller ' . $child . '!');`

I'm not sure if this is something to do with VQMOD or eWay extension. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: did you check line 47 in \vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_controller.php ?

Comment: Yeah I just updated the question. Not sure why it's complaining it could not load the controller.

Comment: Do you have a controller file named `eway.php` in `catalog/controller/payment` folder ?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache of vqmod, and then see if the problem insists?

Comment: @JonidBendo I already tried clearing everything from vqcache folder. That does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to try:

1. Check whether you've a file named  `eway.php` in `catalog/controller/payment` folder.
2. Verify the class name of that file: `class ControllerPaymentEway extends Controller {`.
3. Check the file permission.

Have a nice day!!

Comment: The eway.php file is there and the class name is `class ControllerPaymentEway extends Controller {`. I'm using Windows. I've given full access to the Users group for that file. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just got a solution to this, see [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=106585#p423511).

Described solution:

New function `hasAction` in system/engine/controller.php missing global $vqmod;

Edit `vqmod/xml/vqmod_opencart.xml`

For `<file name="system/engine/controller.php">`

Change:

```
<search position="before" index="1"><![CDATA[$vqmod->modCheck($action->getFile()]]></search>
```

Into

```
<search position="before"><![CDATA[if (file_exists($vqmod->modCheck($action->getFile()))) {]]></search>
```

Comment: I am using the latest versions of OC 1.5.6.1 and VQMOD 2.4.1. The new vqmod has different code from what you've mentioned above. It has something like this: `<search position="replace" regex="true"><![CDATA[~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~]]></search><add><![CDATA[$1$2(VQMod::modCheck($3)]]></add>` in the `vqmod/xml/vqmod_opencart.xml` file. Not sure if I need to make any changes there. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you on 1.5.6 and VQMOD 2.4.

The error appeared because I had previously installed an older version of the official eWay module.

This old version of the module left over a folder in `catalog\controller\payment\eWay folder`.

Delete this `eway subfolder` as the only `eWay` file here should be `catalog\controller\payment\eway.php`

It seems that the controller function gets confused and tried to load the folder instead of the `sway.php` file.

This fixed the problem for me using eWay Rapid 3.1 Transparent Direct Version.

Best of Luck!

Oliver

Comment: Here is what I've observed - I was initially working on localhost and none of the eWay module versions worked. I then tried it on the live site and both eWay Rapid 3.0 and 3.1 worked on the live site. On localhost, eWay Rapid 3.0 gave the trigger error I mentioned above and Rapid 3.1 gave this error: `POST Error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain URL: https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodes`. Not sure what exactly this is - perhaps it's because my localhost does not have SSL installed? My live site also doesn't have SSL but it didn't give any error.

Comment: It's worked on the live site, which is fine but I am still unable to figure out why it never worked on localhost. Oliver, does it work on your localhost?

Comment: never tried on our localhost. sorry. sounds like your live site may have a host shared ssl certificate.. from memory this was a requirement to get eway working.